# Can we have a visual distinction for posts that have been deleted in the 10k tools?

Tags: feature-request, flags, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, 10k-tools

I was just flag handling when I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311097/1008938) post (10k link). It had two perfectly valid "not and answer" flags from about 10 minutes ago. I re-raised the flag, only to realize after clicking on the question that the answer had been deleted by a diamond mod 11 hours ago.

So, now I've given the diamonds just one more flag to think about. While this isn't such a big problem, I'd still like a visual for deleted posts in the 10k tools so I don't beat a dead horse.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if deleted posts were removed from the flag queue visible to 10k users? Though, I think little changes to the 10k tools are fairly pointless... it needs more than tinkering.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: I like that idea.

Comment: You shouldn't be beating any kind of horse, let alone a dead one ;)

Comment: @mattytommo: Good point. Crying over spilled milk? Debugging over legacy code :)?

Comment: Weird, I thought that deleting a post should automatically clear all the associated flags. You remember when the flags were raised? Maybe 10K users didn't notice it was already deleted and flagged it again after it was already deleted.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That seems to be what must have happened. Do 10k flags go through the 10k queue?

Comment: @Linuxios yes of that I'm certain: flag is a flag, no matter who sent it. (even mods can flag as far as I know :)) I think there was once a bug that you could see your own flags in the 10K tools.